# CGI script return 500 Internal Server Error from web, although work from command line

Tags: apache, http, cgi, firewall, almalinux

OS: AlmaLinux 8.8. Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (AlmaLinux). Command:
`perl /home/user1/public_html/test.cgi` return:

```
Content-type:text/html

Hello!
```

File properties:
`-rwxr-xr-x. 1 nobody nobody unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0  88 Jul 15 12:57 test.cgi`

But when you try to run it from the web, like example.com/test.cgi you got the following error:
`[Sat Jul 15 13:38:50.943316 2023] [cgid:error] [pid 2099193:tid 140664406800128] [client 172.71.182.34:24506] AH01241: error spawning CGI child: exec of '/home/user1/public_html/test.cgi' failed (No such file or directory): /home/user1/public_html/test.cgi`
`[Sat Jul 15 13:38:50.943677 2023] [cgid:error] [pid 2099193:tid 140664406800128] [client 172.71.182.34:24506] End of script output before headers: test.cgi`

File exist:

```
stat /home/user1/public_html/test.cgi
  File: /home/user1/public_html/test.cgi
  Size: 88              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 9729        Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1003/  user1)   Gid: ( 1003/  user1)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0
Access: 2023-07-15 12:57:07.393297167 +0300
Modify: 2023-07-15 12:57:01.240297226 +0300
Change: 2023-07-15 13:51:06.171266280 +0300
 Birth: 2023-07-15 12:57:01.240297226 +0300
```

SELinux in permissive mode:

```
getenforce
Permissive
```

Please, help find out what prevent test.cgi from running? Thank you in advance.

I've checked, that http and https are allowed in Firewall.